# Instagram: Limit results on User Search

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to search for a user using the APIs provided by Instagram and I want to limit number of users returned in the API call. Currently, I am getting a list of all the users who match the query string.

I tried passing the count parameter but that is not working and I am still getting a list of all users.

Is there a way to limit the number of users returned in the response and to provide pagination? If not, what is the maximum number of users that can be returned?

```
API Used: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=searchQuery&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Reference: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Answer (score 1):

use `&count=` it works:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=kevin&count=3&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

this API call will return 3 results.

Comment: I am passing q=p&count=1 but I am getting 2 users whose names start with P. Is there any lower limit on the number of users it returns?